# Whats the best way to check whether one image is somewhere on/similar to another image?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, compare

I want to use openCV to check whether an image is somewhere on another image. This other image could also be a photo. I dont want to know the position or anything, I just want to know whether the image is there or not - or, if the images are "equal enough".

Example: I use my iphone to take a photo of a static object. Now, one day later I take this photo again and I want to check if it is the mostly the same object.

Whats the best way to do this? I alos tried CVMatchTemplate (but was not able to get a working check) and CVNorm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precisely Compare 2 images for differences using OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644787/precisely-compare-2-images-for-differences-using-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [SURF](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/feature_detection.html) (Speeded Up Robust Features) can to this.
I used it to check if an template image can be found on objects along an moving conveyor belt.
Have a look on this [page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp), it describes the usage of SURF with the EMGU-OpenCV wrapper classes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I actually used OpenCV (C# implementation) to do this, but I think I will upgrade to some "more intelligent" algorithms (e.g. SURF) instead of "simple comparing" methods.